# socat wait for answer

Tags: socat

I use this in a script

```
echo $(echo "sign 00:07:32:46:04:75" | socat UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.192.0.2:9000 -)
```

but this does immediately stop and I get no answer from the server

if I do

```
echo $(echo "sign 00:07:32:46:04:75" | socat -t5 UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.192.0.2:9000 -)
```

it always waits the `5 seconds` also when the repsonse would be available after 1 second.

Is there a way to stop the command immediatley after I received the first message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the answer is one newline-delimited line of text, with `bash`, you could always do:

```
IFS= read -r answer < <(
  echo 'sign 00:07:32:46:04:75' |
    socat -t 5 - UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.192.0.2:9000)
```

That would return as soon as there's an answer and `socat` would be left running in background for the remaining time.

In `zsh`, you'd need to add a `&` at the end of the `echo|socat` pipeline for it not to wait for it. You may actually want to add it for `bash` as well to be future-proof in case `bash` decides to change the behaviour in the future.

If the answer can be more than one line or is not newline delimited, with `zsh` you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/system
(echo 'sign 00:07:32:46:04:75' |
  socat -t 5 - UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.192.0.2:9000 &) | sysread answer
```

The `sysread` builtin does *one* `read()` system call of size 8192. That assumes `socat` writes the answer on the pipe in *one* `write()` system call (which it does).

Portably, you could always resort to `dd` for that:

```
answer=$(
  (echo 'sign 00:07:32:46:04:75' |
    socat -t 5 - UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.192.0.2:9000 &) |
    dd bs=8192 count=1 2> /dev/null
)
```

(note that command substitution strips all trailing newline characters).

If you wanted to avoid `socat` hanging around for those few extra seconds after that, you could do something like:

```
answer=$(
  (echo 'sign 00:07:32:46:04:75' |
    sh -c 'echo "$$"
           exec socat -t 5 - UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.192.0.2:9000 &
  ) | {
    IFS= read pid
    dd bs=8192 count=1 2> /dev/null
    kill -s PIPE "$pid"
  }
)
```

Comment: thx for the great answer!